# ByRef argument type mismatch - Access VB

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am receiving a ByRef argument type mismatch. The following code (varFile specificaly) is highlighted for the error:

```
Call InsertCMS_Reports_2ndSave(varFile)
```

Here is my form:

Option Compare Database

```
'Private Sub Command0_Click()
Private Sub cmdFileDialog_Click()

'Requires reference to Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library.

   Dim fDialog As Office.FileDialog
   Dim varFile As Variant

   'Clear listbox contents.
   'Me.FileList.RowSource = ""

   'Set up the File Dialog.
   Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
   With fDialog
      'Allow user to make multiple selections in dialog box.
      .AllowMultiSelect = True

      'Set the title of the dialog box.
      .Title = "Please select one or more files"
     .InitialFileName = "C:\Users\ABCDEF\Desktop\CCCEEe CMS Reports"

      'Clear out the current filters, and add our own.

      .Filters.Clear
      '.Filters.Add "Access Databases", "*.MDB; *.ACCDB"
      .Filters.Add "Access Projects", "*.txt"
      '.Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"

      'Show the dialog box. If the .Show method returns True, the
      'user picked at least one file. If the .Show method returns
      'False, the user clicked Cancel.
      If .Show = True Then
         'Loop through each file selected and add it to the list box.
         For Each varFile In .SelectedItems
           ' Me.FileList.AddItem varFile
         Call InsertCMS_Reports_2ndSave(varFile)
         Next
      Else
         MsgBox "You clicked Cancel in the file dialog box."
      End If
   End With
End Sub
```

Module Code:

```
Function InsertCMS_Reports_2ndSave(FileName As String)
    'DoCmd.DeleteObject CopyOfCOMPRPT_CE, "CMS_Reports_2ndSave"
     DoCmd.TransferText acImportFixed, "CMS_Reports_Import", _
    "CMS_Reports_Import", "C:\Users\A088982\Desktop\January CMS reports for Centene\FileName"
    CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE CopyOfCOMPRPT_CE SET FileName = 'HLTH_COMPRPT_1701011028174_h0062.txt' WHERE FileName is NULL", dbFailOnError
End Function
```

Comment: Thats not VB.NET code; access-vba IsNot VB.NET.  please fix the tags (maybe add VB6 if that is what it really is - the words on the tags provide guidance)

Comment: @Plutonix fixed, thank you!

Comment: What arguments does `InsertCMS_Reports_2ndSave()`  declare?

Comment: @AlexK Hi Alex, that is a import specification that I had saved

Comment: Yes, but what does the first line of it look like? - You passing it a string but if it expects something else thats the problem.

Comment: @AlexK I have updated my post to include my module code

Comment: @AlexK I ended up changing FileName As String to FileName as Variant (thanks to your hint), and I do not see there, I am going to run my form to make sure its fine.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're receiving this error is because you've dimensioned `varFile` as a variant, however your function is expecting a string.  Try this instead:

`Function InsertCMS_Reports_2ndSave(FileName)`